# Why it's a open neighbourhood?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, topological-groups, local-field

Suppose $F$ is a non-Archimedean local field, thus $F$ is the field of fractions
of a discrete valuation ring $\mathfrak{o} $.
Let $\mathfrak{p} $ be the maximal ideal of $\mathfrak{o}$, if $\mathfrak{w}$ is the prime element of $F$,then $x\in \,F$  can be write as $x=u\mathfrak{w}^n$, which $u\in \,\mathfrak{o} ^{\times},n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

The $F$ carries an absolute value
$$\left\| x \right\| =q^{-n},\left\| 0 \right\| =0, q>0 $$

Which give a metric on $F$.

My questions are: why

$$\mathfrak{p} ^n=\left\{ x\in \,\,F:\left\| x \right\| \leqslant q^{-n} \right\} ,n\in \mathbb{Z} 
 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$

are open subsets of $F$?

Comment: Perhaps you meant "open subsets" rather than "open subgroups"?

Comment: Yes, open subgroup.

Comment: Back up then, and connect how $q$ is tied to $x$ when you define "an absolute value" on $F$.  It seems unrelated both to $x$ and to the setup in your first paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, partly because there seem to be some undefined symbols ($q$, $a$).

Is your question why a set of the form $\left\{x\in F\mid \lVert x\rVert\leq q^{-n}\right\}$ for some $n$ is open? Intuitively, this is because there are gaps between the possible values of the norm. Assuming $q>1$, you find $$\left\{x\in F\mid \lVert x\rVert\leq q^{-n}\right\}=\left\{x\in F\mid \lVert x\rVert< \frac{q^{-(n-1)}+q^{-n}}{2}\right\}.$$
which is an open set.

The reason for this equality is as follows. We have $q^{-(n-1)}>q^{-n}$, so any $x$ in the set on the left is also in the set on the right. On the other hand, if $x$ is not in the set on the left, then $q^{-n}<\lVert x\rVert$. But then $\lVert x\rVert$ is at least $q^{-(n-1)}$, so $x$ is also not in the set on the right.

Note that $\frac{q^{-(n-1)}+q^{-n}}{2}$ is more or less arbitrary. We could have taken any value $a$ with $q^{-n}<a<q^{-(n-1)}$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't define  $q$ and $a$, your answer is what I need, thanks.